# Rails 2 : ArgumentError on respond_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, rest

I'm given to understand the conventional way of formatting a given object (say @user) is the following :

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html  
  format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
  format.json { render :json => @user}
end
```

I have the following code in my controller :

```
@selected_criteria = @criteria[0][1]   
@home_members = current_user.my_home_members(@selected_criteria).paginate(:per_page => HOME_MEMBERS_TO_SHOW_PER_PAGE, :page => 1)
respond_to do |format|
  format.html  
  format.xml  { render :xml => @home_members }
  format.json { render :json => @home_members}
end
```

Which gives an empty response, and the error log gives :

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)):
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:33:in `matches'
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:32:in `matches'
```

I don't know what I am missing, is there another argument I have to pass ?

Comment: Yes, you are expected to pass 1 argument, but you have not passed any arguments. Atleast that is what your error log says. Which one is line 33?

Comment: I'm not sure but I have a few suggestions. Do you have a json gem installed? It don't remember for sure but I think you get .to_json only if a gem is installed. Try being explicit and make the calls like @home_members.to_xml etc. Finally, does this happen only when you vist home.xml and home.json but the html version works ok?

Comment: @DeepakPrasanna : Line 33 is the json